# Is it possible to specify a default value for all parameters simultaneously in a function?

Tags: ruby, function

If I have a function like this:

```
def foo(a="this", b="this", c="this")
end
```

Is there some option to set a default value for all of them at the same time? Something like:

```
def foo(DEFAULT="this", a, b, c)
end
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want. Even *if* what you want *would* work, the two examples don't do the same thing. The first one creates *three different strings* and gives *three different* objects as default values for the three different parameters, whereas the second example creates *one single string* and assigns *the same string* to all three parameters. So, if the content of the method were `b.replace("foo"); p a, b, c`, the first would print `this foo this`, the second would print `foo foo foo`. So, it is completely unclear what your goal is.

Answer (score -1):

### Metaprogramming Local Variables

If you're trying to create positional method-local variables that can be overridden, you can use a bit of metaprogramming using the current [Binding](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Binding.html). For example:

```
def foo a=nil, b=nil, c=nil
  %i[a b c].map do |v|
    binding.local_variable_get(v) ||
    binding.local_variable_set(v, "this")
  end
  [a, b, c]
end
```

This will do what you seem to want. For example:

```
foo 1
#=> [1, "this", "this"]

foo 1, 2
#=> [1, 2, "this"]
```

### Other Approaches

Other approaches may include the [deprecated](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/) use of options hashes with:

- an options hash using `Hash.new("this")` in the method signature
- a [Hash#default=](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-i-default-3D) defined inside the body of the method
- the use of [Hash#fetch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) to return a default value when reading your options hash

If your goal is just to DRY up your code, it may be better to consider [keyword arguments](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/ruby-2-keyword-arguments) (e.g. `def foo **kwargs`) rather than positional arguments, but your mileage may vary.